# When users type "/register" bot is inserting "0" instead of their "user id"

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

When users type `/register`, then my bot is inserting `"0"` instead of their `user id` in phpMyAdmin.

This is the code, what's causing this problem?

```
if (strpos($message, "/register") === 0) {

    $che = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $id . "' ");
    $check = mysqli_fetch_assoc($che);

    if ($id != $check['id']) {
        mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE count SET users = users + 1");
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(id) VALUES('$id')");
        sendMessage($chatId, "<u>Done</u>", $message_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `$id` come from? I strongly suspect your code is doing something like `INSERT INTO users(id) VALUES ('register')` and that's getting turned into `0` because MySQL does that by default when an invalid string is put into a numeric column.

Comment: (This code is also highly vulnerable to SQL injection and is unsafe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Where is $id defined?